# How do we handle freeing a BST when malloc fails in the middle of our recursive build?

Tags: c, recursion, malloc, binary-search-tree, free

I've done some looking around and can't really find a good source that even addresses the idea.

First: It's well known that we should always check if malloc() and realloc() return null. This is commonly done in some way similar to:

```
Word* temp;
if ((temp = (Word*)malloc(sizeof(Word))) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "unable to malloc for node.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

However, we also generally build binary search trees in a recursive manner, like so:

```
void buildTree(Word** tree, const char* input) {
    //See if we have found the spot to insert the node.
    //Do this by checking for NULL
    if (!(*tree)) {
        *tree = createNode(input);
        return;
    }
    //else, move left or right accordingly.
    if (strcmp(input, (*tree)->data) < 0)
        buildTree(&(*tree)->left, input);
    else
        buildTree(&(*tree)->right, input);
    return;
}
```

So, what do we do if we start working with massive data sets and malloc() fails to allocate memory in the middle of that recursive buildTree function? I've tried a number of things from keeping track of a "global error" flag and a "global head" node pointer and it just seems to be more and more messy the more I try. Examples working with building BSTs rarely seem to give any thought to malloc() failing, so they aren't really helpful in this regard.

I can logically see that one answer is "Don't use recursion and return the head of the tree each time." and while I can see why that would work, I'm an undergraduate TA and one of the things we use BSTs to teach is recursion. So, saying "don't use recursion" to my students when we are TEACHING recursion would be self-defeating.

Any thoughts, suggestions, or links would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why would you need a global error flag when your `buildTree` function could have a perfectly good return type? (That is, why not just make `buildTree` return an error code, and then propagate that up on failures?)

Comment: You aren't wrong, but that doesn't really address  the question... Unless I misunderstand you? Even if I did the "c-style" error-handling of return an int to represent success or failure, I still wouldn't know how to handle freeing the nodes that were allocated before the malloc() failed...  

Can you maybe expand on what you were thinking if I seem to have misunderstood what you were suggesting?  How would I check for the result of a recursive call within the function? Can you maybe provide an example? I think you might be on to something, but i'm not sure...

Comment: You could propagate the error code up all the way and have the caller be responsible for freeing the tree if it's only partially built.  You could make it somewhat nicer by introducing a wrapper function to perform the initial `buildTree` call, and then that function would be responsible for cleanup on failure.

Comment: +1 I'll have to give this a shot in the morning. If it works i'll report back. If I have more questions i'll also report back.

Comment: The traditional way of handling this type of clean-up in C, at least in larger applications, is to set up multiple allocators (memory arenas) which may be freed in their entirety when one phase of execution has completed. Of course if you're just going to exit afterwards then it should be noted that C environments not automatically freeing all memory at exit are virtually non-existent these days, so unless you have a particular oddball platform in mind then I just wouldn't bother in this case. Especially not for a teaching example not directly focused on error handling.

Comment: @doynax I didn't know that; so you're saying that most environments will automatically free the memory if it isn't cleaned up by the program? Such as on the command line on a linux/unix environment and within major IDEs such as Netbeans?

Comment: @TylerN: That's correct. If it didn't then misbehaving programs would gradually eat up all of the memory in the system. This nicety isn't guaranteed but any modern desktop operating system certainly will, certainly anything with memory protection to protect misbehaving/malicious processes from treading on each others toes.

Comment: regarding the example call to malloc(): 'malloc(sizeof(Word))' this will malloc 4 (or 8 bytes, depending on the underlying architecture) probably not what you want.   in C, do not cast the returned value from malloc() as it is a void* so can be assigned to any pointer.

Comment: @user3629249 Word here is a defined struct. It's not a traditional "word". It's misleading without more context, but I took it from an assignment where we are dealing with parsing strings and check whether or not they are spelt correctly. And I am having them typecast precisely because it is a void pointer and I want them to have a compile error if they try to assign it to the wrong data type. These are second semester students. 

Genuinely, thank you for trying to offer advice though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We usually use a return error and let the caller free it, after all it could very well free other non critical resources and try to insert the node again.

```
#define BUILD_OK     0
#define BUILD_FAILED 1

int buildTree(Word** tree, const char* input) {
    int res;

    //See if we have found the spot to insert the node.
    //Do this by checking for NULL
    if (!(*tree)) {
        if (!(*tree = createNode(input)))
            return BUILD_FAILED;

        //Maybe other checks

        return BUILD_OK;
    }
    //else, move left or right accordingly.
    if (strcmp(input, (*tree)->data) < 0)
       res = buildTree(&(*tree)->left, input);
    else
       res = buildTree(&(*tree)->right, input);

    return res;
}
```

Comment: OH! -_- well, I hadn't considered freeing the nodes bottom-up. I was fighting with trying to maintain a reference to the tree head as it was being built. Which, still doesn't wouldn't change after the first call... huh. Well, anyway, thanks!

Comment: the suggested 'bottom up' free sequence will not work as the recursive path does not visit all nodes in the tree.  So no freeing, rather let the original caller of the function handle the error

Comment: @user3629249 Thanks for catching that. I haven't had a chance to test the solution either way, but what you said makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: In this particular case, I think the original version of this answer would work with what code we're given in the question. Each call to `buildTree` creates 1 node and recursively calls `buildTree` once more (there is no tree recursion).  When failure occurs, recursive freeing isn't necessary; all descendant nodes would already have been freed.

Comment: @jamesdlin I think user3629249 is still right. An adapted version that free the nodes bottom-up can still be made because when working with ptr to ptr we can set a freed ptr to null and so after the recursive call we can tell if one sub-tree need to be freed (it is non null) and free it (with another function). But it is not elegant in my opinion, I prefer the return only version.